# Laravel - Signup Activation Mail Could not be sent in Laravel

Tags: angular, laravel, postman

I am using Laravel-5.8 and Angular-7 for my web application. From Laravel backend, I am using mailtrap for activation email after successful user signup.

AuthController

```
    public function signup(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required|string|min:2',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|string|confirmed|min:6'
        ]);
        $user = new User([
            'name' => $request->name,
            'email' => $request->email,
            'password' => bcrypt($request->password),
            'activation_token' => str_random(60)
        ]);
        $user->save();
        $avatar = Avatar::create(strtoupper($user->name))->getImageObject()->encode('png');
        Storage::put('avatars/'.$user->id.'/avatar.png', (string) $avatar);
        $user->notify(new SignupActivate($user));
        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Successfully created user!'
        ], 201);
    }

    public function signupActivate($token)
    {
        $user = User::where('activation_token', $token)->first();
        if (!$user) {
            return response()->json([
                'message' => 'This activation token is invalid.'
            ], 404);
        }
        $user->active = true;
        $user->activation_token = '';
        $user->email_verified_at = Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString();
        $user->save();
        return $user;
    }
```

After a successful signup, an activation email is to be sent to the user. On POSTMAN, the signup was successful with confirmation message. It is even in the database, but activation email was not sent to the user, not even in the spam.

[image: postman message]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, you don't add mail functionality in your code.
For mail functionality using `Laravel Mailtrap`, Please check the following step.

1. First you need to setup using command.

> php artisan make:mail NewUserNotification

2. Please check below code for sending mail from a particular method.

   ```
   Mail::send('emails.reminder', ['user' => $user], function ($m) use ($user) {
            $m->from('hello@app.com', 'Your Application');
            $m->to($user->email, $user->name)->subject('Your Reminder!');
       });
   ```

For more reference, you need to check laravel documentation. [click here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/mail)

Answer (score 0):

issue is in your code.

```
$user->notify(new SignupActivate($user));
```

Please use eloquent create method because:

Once we have made the attributes mass assignable, we can use the create method to insert a new record in the database. The create method returns the saved model instance. Eg:

```
$flight = App\Flight::create(['name' => 'Flight 10']);
```

in your case $user return true or false.

```
$user = User::create(['name'=>$name,'email'=>$email,'activation_token'=>$token]);
$user->notify(new SignupActivate($user->activation_token));
```